# Разбор прошивки

Tags: c, c++-cli

Есть код из прошивки, который при опросе usb девайса должен вернуть определенное значение, работаю с устройством как с файлом (c++cli). Подскажите, как правильно отправить запрос что бы получить данные? Или может я что то отпустил, скажите в какую сторону смотреть, я начинающий и хочу разобраться)

Я пробую отправить такую последовательность байт <0x40><0x26><0x00>
Возможно нужен еще адрес конечной точки?

```
#define  USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR                            0x40
#define  USB_REQ_TYPE_MASK                              0x60

static uint8_t  usbd_cdc_Setup (void  *pdev, 
                            USB_SETUP_REQ *req)
{
uint16_t len=USB_CDC_DESC_SIZ;
uint8_t  *pbuf=usbd_cdc_CfgDesc + 9;
uint8_t i;
switch (req->bmRequest & USB_REQ_TYPE_MASK)
{
    case USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR:
    {   
        memPrintNum = 0;
        switch(req->bRequest)
        {       
            case 0x26: //Head temp req
            {
                if( (req->wValue) == 0x00)
                {
                    safeprintf(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,"%.1f",(float)printer.HeadTemp);
                    safeputchar(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,0xf8);
                    safeputchar(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,'C');
                    USBD_CtlSendData (pdev, (uint8_t *)&printfText, memPrintNum);  
                }
                break;
            }   
            case 0x27: //power on counter
            {
                if( (req->wValue) == 0x00)
                {
                    safeprintf(PUTCHAR_MEMORY,"%don",EEPROM_stat.powerOn);
                    USBD_CtlSendData (pdev, (uint8_t *)&printfText, memPrintNum);  
                }
                break;
            }   

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возьмите библиотеку *libusb-1.0* или выше и не изобретайте велосипед без необходимости.

Comment: @0andriy ели использовать данную библиотеку, нужно будет устанавливать драйвер на устройство ?